# Cassandra with Stratio lucene index

Tags: cassandra, lucene, full-text-search, stratio, cassandra-lucene-index

I have installed Data-Sax Cassandra community edition(2.2.3) on my machine and I want to use full text Search.
I have downloaded the Stratio lucene index 2.2.3 and copied it to the Cassandra lib folder but when I execute the command to create index as below

```
   CREATE CUSTOM INDEX tweets_index ON tweets (lucene)
   USING 'com.stratio.cassandra.lucene.Index'
   WITH OPTIONS = {
  'refresh_seconds' : '1',
  'schema' : '{
    fields : {
        id    : {type : "integer"},
        user  : {type : "string"},
        body  : {type : "text", analyzer : "english"},
        time  : {type : "date", pattern : "yyyy/MM/dd", sorted : true},
        place : {type : "geo_point", latitude:"latitude",    longitude:"longitude"}
    }
}'
};
```

I get exception ServerError:

```
    ErrorMessage code=0000 [Server error] message="java.lang.RuntimeEx
   ception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:    
    com.stratio.cassandra.lucene.Index"
```

I also tried to build it  using maven and update the installation , but no success. Also I copied the jar files to my JDK ext folder and tried again without any success.

Cheers,
jereesh

Comment: Is there any specific reason to use version 2.2.3? if not switch to latest version and you can create a Solr node which uses underlying CFS to store indexes and is much faster.

Comment: @mbaxi , 2.2.3 is the stable version right?.

Comment: Yeh sorry I got confused with enterprise edition(v4.8) which provides inbuilt integration with Solr.

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure you have copied the proper index JAR file into Cassandra's lib path?

You can download, build and patch your Cassandra installation this way:

```
git clone https://github.com/Stratio/cassandra-lucene-index.git
cd cassandra-lucene-index
git checkout 2.2.3.2
cd mvn clean package -Ppatch -Dcassandra_home=<PATH_TO_CASSANDRA>
```

Please ensure that `<PATH_TO_CASSANDRA>` contains the following:

```
CHANGES.txt     
lib
LICENSE.txt
conf
logs
NEWS.txt
data
pylib
NOTICE.txt
interface
switch_snappy
bin
javadoc
tools
```

Otherwise, you can download DSC community 2.2.3 from http://downloads.datastax.com/community/dsc-cassandra-2.2.3-bin.tar.gz

I hope it helps.

Comment: Yes I did It seems to be working when the Cassandra is being started from the batch file . But seems to be not picking if I start the Datasax  Cassandra Community Server Service